# Is this a variable scoping bug in NodeJS or do I just need more sleep

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

Working on a NodeJS project, I came a across this very unexpected behaviour that I can't figure a way around - it seems like a bug to me, but perhaps I'm simply misunderstanding how NodeJS modules operate.

I've reduced it into a testcase as follows:

**mod.js module**

```
exports.process = function(obj) { obj.two = 'two'; };
```

**test.js file**

```
var testObj = {one: 'one'};


console.log(['Before:', testObj]);

var cachedObj = testObj;
require('./mod').process(cachedObj);

console.log(['After:', testObj]);
```

Then running `$ node test.js` gives me this:

```
[ 'Before:', { one: 'one' } ]
[ 'After:', { one: 'one', two: 'two' } ]
```

I'm assigning the value of `testObj` to `cachedObj`, and `testObj` is never being passed to the module method. `testObj` should (as far as I can see) **never** be modified at all.

In fact, `cachedObj` should surely never be modified either, as it is never returned from the `mod.process` method. Where am I going wrong?

(running Node 0.6.9)

Comment: You can pass multiple arguments to `console.log`; you don't need an array.

Comment: Cheers - it was actually different custom logging function hastily edited to `console.log` for the benefit of SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's perfectly expected behavior.

Variables in JavaScript are passed by reference, so the original object is mutated by the assignment in `process`.

Comment: This is something of a revelation.. how have I missed this after years working with JS. For future reference - any advice for object cloning patterns? I assume Object.create() will work in Node, but I guess IE7 might be a different issue...

Comment: I can think of a couple approaches: jQuery has deep copy mode in its `$.extend` function; `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`; ... oh, and heh, Stack Overflow search. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: I did find that Q while searching, but the options are `eval`, `JSON` (IE8+) or jQuery (non-native). I suppose recursion is the next best fallback option then? Who knows I may never need it, I seemingly haven't sofar...

Comment: The source for $.extend is here, if you want to take a look for any purpose. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L303

Comment: Wow. That's significantly simpler than I expected it to be. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are passed by reference.

```
var testObj = {one: 'one'}; // <--- Object
var cachedObj = testObj; // cachedObj and testObj point to the same object,
```

Since `cachedObj` and `testObj` point to the same object (`cachedObj === testObj` is `true`), modifying a property of `cachedObj` will also result in a modified `testObj`.

Answer (score 1):

`cachedObj` and `testObj` refers to the same object literal, so if you modify one variable, it is of course seen in both since the variables are just aliases referring to the same object.

Also, objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, so if you modify it inside process.js, the object will be modified.