# Simplistic Javascript array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var a = [], b = [];
a.push('a');
a.push('b');
a.push('c');
b = a;
b.push('d');
console.log(a);
```

Why is a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] ?, how to avoid this cross reference when doing b=a; I would like just to have 2 separates objects, independants

and at the end a = ["a", "b", "c"], and b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Comment: You need to clone the array to have separate objects

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because variables reference objects, they do not copy them.

You can use

```
var a = [], b = [];
a.push('a');
a.push('b');
a.push('c');
b = a.slice();
b.push('d');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a to b, you are actually assigning a reference to a. So any change made to b will also affect a. To do what you really wanted, try:

```
b = [].concat(a);
```

which will make an actual copy of a.

Answer (score 1):

In JS arrays are also objects (instance of `Array` object) and as such objects in JS are assigned by reference not by value, so when you do:

```
b = a
```

`b` is now assigned by reference to `a`, hence it will affect the `a` array.

To do what you want to do, you can do:

```
b = a.slice();
```

Here is an example:

```
var a = [], b = [];
a.push('a');
a.push('b');
a.push('c');
b = a.slice();
b.push('d');
console.log(a);
```

**Result:**

```
[a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because assignment does not copy variable content. (See the related [Is this a variable scoping bug in NodeJS or do I just need more sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429058/is-this-a-variable-scoping-bug-in-nodejs-or-do-i-just-need-more-sleep/9429096) question.)

For arrays, you could use `concat` to create a (shallowly) copied array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [].concat(a)
b.push(4)
```

... or `slice`as the other answers say.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do `b = a` both `a` and `b` point to the same array in memory; you need to push the elements to both `a` and `b` separately, or once you push elements to `a` you can loop through it and push the same to `b`, e.g.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){ b.push( a[i] ); }
```